# Excel function broke

Tags: vba, excel

How could I get the following function to work?

```
Public Function DataRange(Somesheet as String, Optional StartCell as String) as Excel.Range
    If StartCell = "" Then
       DataRange =ThisWorkbook.Sheets( Somesheet).Range( ThisWorkbook.Sheets( Somesheet)_ 
                  .Cells(1,1).End(xldown),ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Somesheet).Cells(1,1).End(xlright))
    Else
       DataRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Somesheet).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Somesheet)_
                   .Range(Startcell).End(xldown),ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Somesheet).Range(Startcell).End(xlright))
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function DataRange(Somesheet as String,  _
                          Optional StartCell as String = "A1") as Excel.Range

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Somesheet)
       Set DataRange = .Range(.Range(Startcell).End(xldown), _
                              .Range(Startcell).End(xltoright))
   End With

End Function
```

Note: `xlToRight` not `xlRight`

Usage:

```
Dim rng
Set rng = DataRange("Sheet1")         'uses default A1 as top-left cell
Set rng = DataRange("Sheet1", "E10")  'uses E10
```

This might work just as well:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Somesheet).Range(Startcell).CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to pass the a parameter and utilize the function?

Comment: subscript out of range with `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Somesheet)`

Comment: Then you need to check you have the right value for `Somesheet`... Not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your `If StartCell = ""`  is not working.  Change the Startcell variable to be a variant, this will then allow you to use the `ismissing` function to check if has been passed and assign your own default if it hasn't.  IsMissing only works with variant data types.  If needed use Cvar() when passing the parameter to the functions